# Pyspark: Get indexes of an RDD elements from another RDD

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

So what I have this two rdds which look like the following:

```
rdd1: [([1, 2], 0), ([2, 4], 1)]
rdd2: [([2, 4], 0), ([1, 2], 1)]
```

What I need is a list which indicates the indexes of rdd1 elements in rdd2. so it would be something like this:

```
[1,0]
```

I know that I can find one specific element index using filter and lambda function but finding the whole thing is a different story. The naive approach top of my head is using a for loop which I am sure is not the best way of handling this problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll have to make keys `hashable` so these can be compared in a distributed way. Lets create a small helper

```
def tupelize_keys(kv):
    k, v = kv
    return tuple(k), v

rdd1H = sc.parallelize([
    ([1, 2], 0), ([2, 4], 1), ([9, 9], 3)
]).map(tupelize_keys)

rdd2H = sc.parallelize([
    ([2, 4], 0), ([1, 2], 1), ([1, 2], 3)
]).map(tupelize_keys)
```

All what is left is a simple outer join:

```
rdd1H.leftOuterJoin(rdd2H).values().collect()
## [(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 0), (3, None)]
```

Please note that this is a multimap and the order is not preserved.